# Getting the 1st input type of a function

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I would like to deduce the first input argument of a function sent as a template parameter. Doing this would allow me to eliminate the parameter `inputtype` if it can be deduced from the function f in the code below.

```cpp
template<typename inputtype, class  Fn, typename ...Params>
inline auto ListMap(const List* const polymorphic_list,
    Fn f,
    Params&&... params) {

    std::vector<decltype(f(nullptr, std::forward<Params>(params)...))> res;
    for (auto lcell = list_head(polymorphic_list); lcell; lcell = lcell->next) {
        const auto v = lcell->data.ptr_value;
        const inputtype* in = static_cast<const inputtype*>(v);
        res.emplace_back(std::move(f(in, std::forward<Params>(params)...)));
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: what is `Fn` supposed to be? Should it work for any callable?

Comment: Yes, the Fn is some function that takes an inputtype, Params... and returns something

Comment: Is v strongly of type inputtype? why do you want to perform an static_cast on it? In other words, what is the type of ptr_value?

Comment: It is, I simply want to static cast it to be able to access the fields that are otherwise inaccessible. Otherwise f would have to take care of the casting itself

Comment: I still don't understand your need, what happens if you pass v straight to f without casting? What is the type of ptr_value? Try to provide us with the way you want to use this function with complete definition of the parameters you are using and also signature of f.

Comment: How is the return type of `f` related to `inputtype`, if at all? Can you set the type of `f` to be something like `std::function<returntype(inputtype*, Params&&...)>`?

Comment: Can `Fn` be a function object or lambda?  Do you consider implicitly doing a hard reinterpret cast a problem? (You should)

Comment: The thing is, you try to make C-style code (your list API) and C++17-style code (variadic templates) work together and I'm not sure if it's possible here. Could you not make `List` be a well-defined templated class defining a `List::value_type` type? This would make your question straightforward.

Comment: @Sinapse I suspect `List::data::ptr_value` to be a `void*`.

Comment: @YSC indeed, if it is void* then there is no way to deduce it automatically here. I'm with you, I believe the problem can be implemented way easier using the modern C++ style. But we don't exactly know the problem yet...

Comment: @YSC I am unfortunately unable to change List as what I'm building takes the list and converts it into a more easily managed format. List::data::ptr_value is indeed a void*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created following sample in which the inputtype template parameter was successfully deduced. Hope you'll be able to integrate the idea into your code.

```
#include <vector>

struct List{
};

struct Data{
    void* ptr_value;
};
struct Node{
    Node* next;
    Data data;
};
Node* list_head(const List*const)
{
    return nullptr;
}

template<typename T, typename inputtype,  typename ...Params>
using Fn = T (*) (inputtype*, Params...);

template<typename T, typename inputtype,  typename ...Params, typename = Fn<T,inputtype, Params...>>
inline auto ListMap(List* polymorphic_list, Fn<T,inputtype, Params...> f,Params&&... params) {

    std::vector<T> res;
    for (auto lcell = list_head(polymorphic_list); lcell; lcell = lcell->next) {
        const auto v = lcell->data.ptr_value;
        inputtype* in = static_cast<inputtype*>(v);
        res.emplace_back(std::move(f(in, std::forward<Params>(params)...)));
    }
    return res;
}

int f(void*,int& x)
{
    return x;
}
int main()
{
    int x = 1;
    auto res = ListMap(new List(),f,x);
}
```